# Power Query — replace all instances of multiple characters in column headings

Tags: function, formula, powerquery, m

I have some M code that replaces every instance of '[' with a '(' in each column heading. However, I would also like to replace every ']' with a ')' in the same step.

How do I do this?

`= Table.TransformColumnNames(Source, each Text.Replace(_, "[", "("))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just have two replacements like in your case, then you can just wrap with another `Text.Replace` function:

```
= Table.TransformColumnNames(Source,
      each Text.Replace(
               Text.Replace(_, "[", "("),
               "]", ")"
           )
  )
```